# How to override user.home property of ant from Jenkins server?

Tags: ant, jenkins

Hi I need some help in overriding the `user.home` property of ant from Jenkins. I created a simple job on jenkins that runs a build script on a slave machine of the master. One of the tasks of the scripts is to use the `user.home` property of ant and access certain files. The problem is that when I try to echo this property from the command line of the slave machine, I see `C:\Users\Administrator` but when I run the exact the same script from the Jenkins server I see `C:\` . This difference is causing the build to fail on Jenkins. Can anyone please tell me what is the reason for this difference? Is there any way I can override this?

I tried having a property called `user.home` in the config file of my job but it doesn't seem to pick it up. Another interesting point is that when I changed the  `user.home` value to some gibberish in the config file and run ant from command line on the slave, it still picks it up as `C:\Users\Administrator`

I am using `ant 1.7.1` and `Jenkins 1.598`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have jenkins running as a different ID than Administrator.  Which is a good thing.

Properties in ant are immutable so you can specify those properties from the ant plugin in jenkins and they'll override any other values. (click advanced under the invoke ant buildstep to see the properties text box).

I'd recommend you not override `user.home` but rather refactor your ant so there is a `config.location` property that defaults to `user.home` but can be overidden to whatever you want from jenkins.  It just seems unnatural to ovrride `user.home`

Comment: So this is a little complicated than that. I'll try and explain it in the best possible way. I created a simple job that invokes `BUILDA.xml` and uses `CONFIGA.INI`. In this build file I basically download some files and do some refactoring. Now, in one of the targets I change my ant build dir a couple of times and use different config files. These are build scripts that I did not write and they use the property `user.home` to access certain files. I tried adding `user.home` in `CONFIGA.INI` but that didn't help. Plus, I run the same job as a different user on different slaves.

Comment: The only workaround I found was to start Jenkins and the slave service as the admin user and re-connect the slaves to the master so that it picks up the latest `user.home`.

You said it is a good thing to start Jenkins using a different ID than Administrator. Why is that?

Comment: It's a security thing.  With the slave process itself and the code it runs.  If the slave is running as admin, a mistake or a malicious user could cause problems.  consider if someone added an exed `cmd rmdir /s /r c:\`  this to your ant build script.  I know it's unlikely but it's best to limit the use of the Administrator account.